# VSCode API: registerCompletionItemProvider doesn't work with "@" trigger symbol

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am trying to use `registerCompletionItemProvider`to add autocompletion inside of JSDoc comments, but my provider doesn't work on the "@" trigger symbol, it is strange, but with other symbols, like "|" or "!" it works fine. I tried to check it with the VSCode debugger but it shows that my `provideCompletionItems` function isn't even called on the "@" trigger symbol.

[That's how it looks like with the "@" symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkTrl.jpg)

[That's how it looks like with the "|" symbol or any other symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXM1M.jpg)

My extension.ts file

```
export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {
  context.subscriptions.push(
     languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES, {
       provideCompletionItems,
     }, "@");
  );
}
```

My `provideCompletionItems`

```
const provideCompletionItems = (
  doc: TextDocument,
  pos: Position
) => {
  let keys = Object.keys(JSDocElements);
  let completions = keys.map(key => {
    // @ts-ignore
    let e = JSDocElements[key];
    let r = new CompletionItem(key + " ");
    r.documentation = e.desc;
    r.kind = CompletionItemKind.Snippet;
    return r;
  });
  const txt = doc.getText();
  const matcher = /\/\*\*[^\*](?:\r|\n|.)*?\*\//g;
  let match = matcher.exec(txt);
  let p = doc.offsetAt(pos);
  while (match) {
    if (match.index > p) {
      match = null;
      break;
    }
    if (match.index < p && match.index + match[0].length > p) {
      break;
    }
    match = matcher.exec(txt);
  }

  if (!match) return [];

  return completions;
};
```